# How to get the Minimun and Maximum zoom level by coordinates

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, gdal2tiles

I am new to GDAL, using the below commands I was able to generate tiles for a particular image. After the image is tiled the min and max zoom levels are decided based on the coordinates provided. My question is, is there any way to get the min and max zoom levels before or after the images are tiled?
It would also be helpful if there is any formula where we can get the min and max zoom levels by the coordinates specified as well as the image.

To get the VRT file:

```
gdal_translate -of VRT -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr 39.3435971735232 -84.44959223275554 39.34221893076454 -84.44729859545232 foo.png foo.vrt
```

To tile the images:

```
gdal2tiles.py foo.vrt
```

Comment: It is unclear if your question is about gdal_translate or gdal2tiles. Could you add complete commands that you use? The file names are not important, they can be foo and bar if you do not want to show them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have changed the question with the required commands @user30184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum zoom level is computed by the pixel size of the original data. It happens around line 172 in the Python script

https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/gdal2tiles.py#L172

```
"Maximal scaledown zoom of the pyramid closest to the pixelSize."
```

If the original pizel size is 1 m then the max zoom level will probably by 18 that corresponds to 0.596 meters https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels

The min zoom level is computer around line 2310 of the script

https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/gdal2tiles.py#L2310

```
        # Get the minimal zoom level (map covers area equivalent to one tile)
```

Comment: Thanks for the links. As I saw the python code internally it's using many methods. Is there any direct formula that will take an image, coordinates as input, and gives min and max zoom level?